# How do I un-select a selected option and refresh values to 1st selected in JqueryMobile?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I have a problem, I want to refresh or un-select a selected value from options dropdown.

I'm able to un-select value , But selected value didn't refresh, and show same.
JqueryMobile:

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="ui-field-contain">
 <select name="mu_part_name" id="mu_part_name">
     <option value="0">First Products</option>
     <option value="1">second Products</option>
     <option selected value="2">Most used Products</option>
     <option value="3">last Products</option>
 </select>
</fieldset>
 <a rel="external" onClick="showpart();"> <input type="button" value="Add">   </a>
```

Jacascript:

```
function showpart(){
$("#mu_part_name").prop("selectedIndex", 0);
var test = $( "#mu_part_name" ).val();
alert(test);
var text = $( "#mu_part_name option:selected" ).text();
alert(text);
```

}

Alert values are changed: Required one: 
But shows the existing selected value :(

I shall be very thankful to you.... :)
thanks in advance...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just tell the select widget to refresh itself: http://api.jquerymobile.com/selectmenu/#method-refresh

```
$("#mu_part_name").prop("selectedIndex", 0).selectmenu( "refresh", true );
```

Comment: I've tried it, But didn't work.. :(
seems generating error, that's why, alerts didn't work too...

Comment: @ArslanTabassum, here is a working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/43nk572m/8/ Where is your code called from?

Comment: Please modify using on click and send me the jsfiddle link.

 <a rel="external" onClick="showpart();"> <input type="button" value="Add"></a>

then in function:
 function showpart(){
    $("#mu_part_name").prop("selectedIndex", 0).selectmenu("refresh", true);;

    var test = $("#mu_part_name").val();
    alert(test);
    var text = $("#mu_part_name option:selected").text();
    alert(text);
    }

Comment: first time should show selected:
after onclick: should change to 1st one selected.

Comment: @ArslanTabassum, works fine: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/43nk572m/9/, technically you should not put a button inside an anchor, and you should avoid inline event handlers: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/43nk572m/10/

Comment: Thanks your example is great :)
But what should be the problem on my side?
i used these files additionaly:
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.4/jquery.mobile-1.4.4.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/jquery.ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

But didn't work on my side?

Comment: Changed the flow: and working fine now....
Thanks again.... this is what i implement
http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/43nk572m/10/